# Stanford classifier - Why?

Tags: weka, stanford-nlp, rapidminer, text-classification

Given Stanford Classifier is relatively new which added values it supplies to users of Weka or RapidMiner working on text ML?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the Stanford classifier qualifies as "new" -- but, in my (admittedly biased) experience it's quite fast and robust at the types of classification problems we often encounter in NLP. That is, in situations where you have a lot of sparse indicator features (e.g., bag of words), but relatively few features fire per example (< 100 or so). On these problems, it is orders of magnitude faster than Weka. I don't have any personal experience with RapidMiner, so I can't say much in the way of comparison there.